# How to set I/O constraints when the device is clocked by the FPGA

Tags: fpga, timing-analysis, sdc

What is the proper way of setting I/O constraints when the device is clocked by the FPGA?
As an example schematic is given below:
[image]
The ADC is clocked from the FPGA. I have generated_clock constraints for both PLL output and Divider (DIV) outputs. Should I need to create a generated clock on the clock o/p pin of the FPGA, and set the I/O delay (set_input_delay) constraints for the FPGA data line with respect to this clock? Or it is better to use a virtual clock, but I have no idea how a virtual clock can estimate the timing to the data line in this case.

I cannot find much information from the following:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683081/22-2/input-and-output-delays-with-virtual-clocks.html